# How to move a table (with UDT as column) to another schema in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table which has a column of user defined type.There is a requirement to move this table along with UDT to another schema. I tried to create table as, the problem is it uses the UTD from original schema. Is there any way to achieve this?

Ex:
User 1:

```
CREATE TYPE employee_t AS OBJECT
(employee_id NUMBER
,employee_name VARCHAR2(30)
,salary NUMBER
,dept_id NUMBER);

CREATE TABLE department
(emp employee_t
,mgr varchar2(40)
,dept_id number
,dept_name varchar2(30));
```

In the above example, department table has a column called emp which is UDT.

Now on user2, if I do the following

`create table department as select * from user1.department`.

Table will be created as follows. Actually I want EMPLOYEE_T also to be moved to user2.

Desc department:

```
Name                                      Null?    Type 
----------------------------------------- -------- -------------------
EMP                                            USER1.EMPLOYEE_T 
MGR                                                VARCHAR2(40)
DEPT_ID                                            NUMBER
DEPT_NAME                                          VARCHAR2(30)
```

Comment: Have you considered using EXPDP/IMPDP?